# SQL Copy Multiple Column from Table 1 in DB A to Table2 in DB B

Tags: sql

I have a table `data_1` with 2 columns I would like to copy over to table sensor_reading. I would like the column `tmp1` in `data_1` to get copied over to `reading` in `sensor_reading`, and the column `dt_s` in `data_1` to get copied over to `reading_time` in table `sensor_reading`.

The following is what I am trying, but I get "Update 0".

```
update sensor_reading 
set reading = data_1.tmp1, 
    reading_time = data_1.dt_s, 
    sensor_id = 1 
from data_1;
```

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data and desired results.

Comment: Do you have any rows in the sensor_reading table? `update` won't copy over rows, you want to use `insert ... from ...` for that.

Comment: You can copy whole DB and then drop the undesired column(If you don't have massive number of columns you don't want)

Comment: Also need to know the JOIN condition(s) for the two tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are trying to do if the data is not already in the table:

```
INSERT sensor_reading (reading, reading_time, sensor_id)
SELECT tmp1, dt_s, 1
FROM data_1
```